# vb.net listbox display tables names from database

Tags: database, vb.net, oledb

I need to list all the tables in the list box from the `database.mdb` file. Not the contents of the tables just the tables name using `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`

I'm new to vb.net, please help.

this is what i have so far.. and i keep getting errors

---

```
    Dim dbpath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
    dbpath = New Uri(dbpath).LocalPath
    TextBox1.Text = dbpath + "\database.mdb"

    Dim userTables As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim connection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source =" textbox1.text
    ' We only want user tables, not system tables
    Dim restrictions() As String = New String(4) {}
    restrictions(3) = "Table"
    connection.Open()
    ' Get list of user tables
    userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)
    connection.Close()
    ' Add list of table names to listBox
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To userTables.Rows.Count - 1 Step i + 1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(userTables.Rows(i)(2).ToString())
    Next
```

Comment: Use the `GetSchema` method of your `OleDbConnection` to populate a `DataTable` with table information.  You can then bind that `DataTable` to your ListBox.  http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/retrieving-database-schema-information.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code segment to display the list of tables in a .mdb file [Click Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2eaf851-fc06-49a1-b7bd-bca76669783e/get-list-of-tables-in-access-using-vbnet-app?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) to get reference

```
Dim userTables As DataTable = Nothing
Dim connection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;//your database path"
' We only want user tables, not system tables
Dim restrictions() As String = New String(4) {}
restrictions(3) = "Table"
connection.Open()
' Get list of user tables
userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)
connection.Close()
' Add list of table names to listBox
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To userTables.Rows.Count - 1 Step i + 1
    ListBox1.Items.Add(userTables.Rows(i)(2).ToString())
Next
```

Comment: userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions) keeps thowing errors

Comment: {"More restrictions were provided than the requested schema ('Tables') supports."}

Answer (score 0):

### seem this the right answer

```
Dim userTables As DataTable = Nothing
Dim connection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
Dim source As String
source = TextDBPath.Text
connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + source
Dim restrictions() As String = New String(3) {}
restrictions(3) = "Table"
connection.Open()
' Get list of user tables
userTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)
connection.Close()
' Add list of table names to listBox
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To userTables.Rows.Count - 1 Step i + 1
    cbox.items.add(userTables.Rows(i)(2).ToString())
Next
```